# While loop executing once(?)

Tags: loops, pascal, freepascal

I've been writing this hangman program in Pascal and I've been looking at this problem for a while and getting nowhere. I originally thought the input was reading a `\n` too, but a bit of `write()` later and that wasn't the case. what happens when I type in `a`, it goes through the loop and does everything right, but then it goes through again with nothing or a new line character or something that isn't visible. I've tried ensuring that `guess` is only getting one character, but that made it loop numerous times with the non-visible character.

If anyone can offer any sort of input as to what's going wrong here that'd be great. Google was actually not a very big help for once

anyways, thanks for anything you can offer.

```
program p1;
const 
  MAX_GUESSES = 6;
  mysteryWord = 'abomination';
  //comparetext(str1,str2);
type
  word = array[0 .. 11] of char;
var 
  guesses : word;
  counter : integer;//for multipurpose counting ;)
  wrong : integer;
  keepGoing : boolean;
  guess : char;
  exists : boolean;
begin
  guesses := '***********';
  wrong := 0;
  keepGoing := true;
  repeat 
    keepGoing := false;
    exists := false;
    writeln('your word is ' + guesses + '.');
    write('You have ');         //this one line is separated into 3
    write(6-wrong);             //because it wont allow (6-wrong) to
    writeln(' wrong guesses left!');//be put in line with strings. 
    write('Guess a letter: ');
    read(guess);
    for counter := 0 to 11 do
    begin
      if (guess = mysteryWord[counter]) then
      begin
        guesses[counter-1] := guess;
        exists := true;
      end;
    end;
    if(exists = false) then wrong := wrong + 1;
    for counter := 0 to 11 do
    begin
      if(guesses[counter] = '*') then keepGoing := true;
    end;
  until ((wrong >= 6) or (keepGoing = false));

end.
```

Comment: "for counter := 0 to 11 do". Strings are "1" based.

Comment: That doesn't change anything.

Comment: Ok. Then go on accessing the 0th and -1th element of your string.

Comment: You won't find your answer by searching "while loop executes only once" online. You have bug(s) in your code. What you need to do is to debug it.

Comment: Well... it works accessing the elements as it is... I've done debugging as I said above. Do you have any suggests to try?

Comment: Why not learn to debug?

Comment: Turn on range checks and you will see what is wrong.

Comment: " I've done debugging as I said above. "  Not very thoroughly or effectively.  You will learn far more if you find out what is wrong yourself than have one of us tell you.  Btw, `word` is an unfortunate choice of name for a variable because there is a numeric datatype of the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace the line **read(guess);** with **readln(guess);** you will only get one character per loop.

If you get replace the line **word = array[0 .. 11] of char;** with **word = array[1 .. 11] of char;** (or alternately get rid of the unnecessary 'word' type altogether and set guesses as a string), run your loops from 1 to 11, and replace the line **guesses[counter-1] := guess;** with **guesses[counter] := guess;**, your program won't have the error of accessing out-of-bounds array locations.

Also it might be nice (when you finally exit the repeat loop) to provide some output text telling the player if they won or lost the game...

...and you could also replace the three lines **write('You have '); write(6-wrong);  writeln(' wrong guesses left!');**, with the single line **writeln('You have ', 6 - wrong, ' wrong guesses left!');**

Comment: THANK YOU!!! In all the tutorial websites I looked at, nothing said anything about the readln() function, I never even thought about trying to do something like that. I do plan on having the stuff at the end of the loop, I just wanted to get that error fixed.